# Runtime.exe failure on Linux

Tags: java, linux, runtime, exec

Struggling to try to launch any program on Linux using Runtime.exec();
Works great on Windows.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/xed": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:592)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:416)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:313)
    at guiExample/com.windyweather.MyCalc.launchProgram(MyCalc.java:276)
```

I've been around the rosy for a few days now.  Found this:

https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

and have incorporated the very last, best, solution there.
I've wrapped the command in a script thinking that the problem was from soffice that I was trying to launch, but that's not it. It won't even launch /usr/bin/xed. At first I tried just xed, but that's a link, so thought the shell might have resolved that. So I tried to get the hard path to the xed program itself. No luck.

Code is here: https://github.com/windyweather/GuiExample

including the full stack trace in

https://github.com/windyweather/GuiExample/blob/master/Linux_Runtime_exec_Failure.txt

Why is this so hard? What obviously stupid thing am I doing wrong?
How could /usr/bin/xed not be there when the same thing typed to a shell works fine. And by the way this is what I get when I ask the shell:

```
darrell@LM19RyzenVM:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/xed
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10232 Dec 11 06:49 /usr/bin/xed
darrell@LM19RyzenVM:~$ /usr/bin/xed
darrell@LM19RyzenVM:~$
```

Thanks.
Sorry. Forgot this.

```
LM19RyzenVM:~$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.7 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04, mixed mode, sharing)
LM19RyzenVM:~$ cat /etc/issue
Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia \n \l
```

Comment: "file not found" error may be caused by the interpreter or a dynamic linked library not being found. There is some difference between the environment of your shell and the environment that Java uses. Try running `file /usr/bin/xed` in your shell, and  `ldd /usr/bin/xed` from Java and in your shell, that should give enough information to see what's happening 
See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378301/linux-executable-fails-with-file-not-found-even-though-the-file-is-there-and-i

Answer (score 0):

If you launch the Jar file on Linux, the program works as expected. I would call that an Eclipse bug. I have seen mention for a few years ago about a similar bug in Eclipse regarding Runtime.exec(). Here's the terminal output from a successful run of the jar file with successful launch of soffice.

```
darrell@LM19RyzenVM:~/CodeJava/zzJarFiles$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.7 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04, mixed mode, sharing)
darrell@LM19RyzenVM:~/CodeJava/zzJarFiles$ java -jar GuiExample_2020_04_23.jar
launchProgram before soffice --impress --show /home/darrell/ImpressTests/ChainTests/ShowTestOne.odp
launchProgram after
ERROR>func=xmlSecCheckVersionExt:file=xmlsec.c:line=188:obj=unknown:subj=unknown:error=19:invalid version:mode=abi compatible;expected minor version=2;real minor version=2;expected subminor version=25;real subminor version=26
ExitValue: 0
darrell@LM19RyzenVM:~/CodeJava/zzJarFiles$
```

I was able to successfully launch: /usr/bin/xed and xed and soffice with options and a slide show file which played as expected.

I'll look for and then report or comment on bugs in eclipse.
xed is just fine on my test system. The problem only occurs when the program is launched with eclipse.

Oh well. That's a couple of days I'm never gonna get back. LOL